# Retrofit 2 Gradle Task to Build APK quits. ClassCastException

Tags: android, gradle, retrofit, classcastexception

Good Day Everyone!

I have just updated my Android Project to use the latest version of Retrofit (v2.0.2). The previous version I was using was v2.0.0-beta ('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1').

Compiling and building the project is fine but when I try to test on the device and allowing Gradle to run the necessary tasks, it suddenly fails with this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileProductionDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
>   ndency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>   Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I need to use the latest version as there are bugs on the BETA version when generating an APK for Marshmallow devices.

It's been almost a week now and I can't seem to resolve this issue. I hope some of you can guide me at least to fix this. I've been hitting roadblocks here and there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to close, restart Android Studio and make a Clean Project in the Build option ?
And check you're Gradle version in your build.gradle if it's the latest version or not.

Comment: Yes, I did. I even tried to invalidate the caches for AS. For Gradle, I'm using  the latest version, v2.13